# How to set query_cache_type=2 on mac?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-cache, query-performance

I want to enable `query_cache_type` and change its value to `DEMAND`.
When I am doing it via terminal its giving this error:

> ERROR 1651 (HY000): Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it

The path for `my.cnf` is `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`.

Answer (score 1):

Could not find proper `my.cnf`, so had to find the preferred location where mysql is searching for `my.cnf` by using the command:

```
mysql --help | grep cnf
```

which displays

```
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

So I created a file  `/etc/my.cnf` with the required settings, restarted the server, and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The cache cannot be enabled dynamically if it was disabled at the start, only the other way around.

Just change the type to 2 in `my.cnf` and restart the server.